# how can i get a labels that are stored from the db when cursor is upon the link

Tags: jquery

My question is like in the form :

[Link](http://www.abhibus.com/bus_search/Hyderabad/3/Anantapur/112/25-09-2014/O/)

if you visit the above link, when the mouse reach on top of the arrival/departure time it shows the pickup/drop points

how it could be possible using jquery/some other

please give me the suggestion

i'm stucked over there....

Comment: Try looking up Ajax and jQuery.  You will need to implement the back end in whatever your server code is written in.  Otherwise, the question is very broad.  You need to define _exactly_ which part you are having trouble with.  You also should show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be using [jQuery cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/).

In terms of populating the data, you could either pre-load the values into the page, or indeed make an asynchronous db call to retrieve data dynamically.

Comment: is it possible for to getting the title label from the db like what you saw in the link, i am using jsp & jquery & mysql

Comment: $.post(url){data:<data>,function(data,stauts){do something()}} by with possible to make an asynchronus call to the db

Comment: Yes. You may wish to call `$.get()` though.  Then your `doSomething(data)` method will return the data from the call.